# Socket.io not showing connection when using a phone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, socket.io

So I've made a server with a little party game, and the idea was that people would connect with their phones, get their cards through player page and one person (game master) could control which are ticked off through the GM page.

It works okay through my browser, I can see connections and make changes with one website to the others.

But when I connect with my phone (ip_adress:8080, like I should) I get the website BUT my server doesn't notify me of a new connection and changes ticked off on my phone don't show up on the other page on my pc browser. It's really bizarre.

Here is my server.js snippet:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static('../client'));
console.log('my socket server is running');

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket){
    console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('tile', sendTiles);

    function sendTiles(textArr){
        socket.broadcast.emit('tile', textArr);  // sends back to all the clients except for the one that sent it
        console.log('server got: ' + textArr);
    }
}
```

If someone thinks more code would help solve this issue I'll gladly add more, but I don't believe that's where the error lies.

Comment: What happens client side in your mobile browsers? Does your socket connect? Have you tried using https?

Comment: @O. Jones I would assume it connects as I get the html file I request, but server on my pc doesn't show a new connection. I don't have the option to open the console on my mobile chrome browser. Could you elaborate on using https?

Comment: The web server in your code as shown uses http, I assume. Port 8080 hints at that.  Connect from a desktop browser and watch the network tab. See what kind of connections are going out.  And, it's a notorious pain in the neck, but you can use desktop chrome devtools to debug mobile chrome.  I've been dealing with that lately.  https://www.plumislandmedia.net/programming/debugging-web-page-code-on-android-from-desktop/  It's possible mobile browsers won't do socket connections unless over https, due to security restrictions.

Comment: @O. Jones I mean I'm using express to make my server, nothing in the network tab tells me anything specifically (it loaded each of my files, and some socket.io requests when I interact with the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved the mystery myself and it was so dumb I'm scared to even post the answer. But here goes because someone could have a similar issue. I'm still not sure why it worked perfectly on my pc, but now it works both on pc and on mobile browser.

In my html page I had /socket.io/socket.io.js in local host. Since I've changed it to my ip everything started connecting.

```
        <script src="http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```